# Material Design TextInput change label and helper size

Tags: android, material-design, android-styles, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

In Material Desing TextInput how do you change the size of the label and helper with styles XML.

I've followed the Material Design [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-kotlin#4), the code lab shows a label that is at least 3 times the size of mine.

My label not readable.

[image]

Codelabs label

[image]

Not sure but here is my XML code

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/new_first_name"
            style="@style/TestInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="First Name"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

My Style XML

```
    <style name="TestInput" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
        <item name="hintTextAppearance">@color/black</item>
        <item name="hintTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">16dp</item>
        <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="maxLines">1</item>
        <item name="helperText">@string/first_name</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="counterMaxLength">20</item>
        <item name="endIconMode">clear_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **`hintTextAppearance`** and **`helperTextTextAppearance`** attributes in the layout or in a custom style.

Something like:

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/App.hintTextAppearance"
            app:helperTextTextAppearance="@style/App.helperTextTextAppearance"
            ...>
```

with:

```
<style name="App.hintTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">xxsp</item>
</style>

<style name="App.helperTextTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption">
    <item name="android:textSize">xxsp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse">
```

app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium.Inverse used.

other solution

```
<style name="CustomTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

app:hintTextAppearance="@style/CustomTextAppearance"
```

Comment: this looks like a solution to adjust the size of the text for a TextInput, I'm looking to adjust the size of the label in a MaterailDesign TextInputLayout.